# Trying to build a Multi select control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is there any good multiselect controls i can use like to have a multiselect option for selecting values from sport [soccer,football,tennis] atrs and entertainment, jobs, science etc. If so where can i get a list of all these types of categories in a text file.

Comment: Are you looking for DHTML multiselect control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the inbuilt ListBox? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4d7ktzs(v=vs.71).aspx Do you have any specific requirements other than being able to select more than one item? As given what you have asked this will do the job.